# Can variables of quantification be repeated?

Tags: logic

For example, is the following valid?

$\forall x \forall x \alpha$

Is so, then how is it evaluated user the basic semantic definition?

Comment: It is discouraged, as it can lead to misinterpretation.  Technically though, the inner quantifier would take precedence, and the outer one would be meaningless.  Contrast that with (forall x)[P(x) implies (forall x) Q(x)].   This is also valid, but again confusing since the x in different places means different things, so substituting needs care.  Check some basic introductions to mathematical logic, e.g. Enderton, for details.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Confusing Notation" Paseman, 2014.06.24

Comment: Whether quantifier reuse is discouraged depends very much on the context. Fragments of first-order logic restricted to a constant number of variables are important in various areas (e.g., finite model theory, and modal logic; the key point for the latter being that the 2-variable fragment of FO is decidable). They of course rely very essentially on the ability to reuse quantified variables.

Comment: This is no good reason to allow this confusing usage. I flag it as an error in my proof-checking software. In all likelihood it would be a typo in any published proof.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is "formally" valid, because usual formation rules allow quantifying a variable which is not *free* in the scope of the quantifier.

In this case the "inner" quantifier bound the free occurrences (if any) of $x$ in $\alpha$. Thus, the "outer" quantifier has "no effect" because there are no free occurrences of $x$ left.

This fact is reflected in the following result :

> $\vDash ∀x \varphi \leftrightarrow \varphi$, if $x \notin FV(\varphi)$.

A good "tutorial" can be extracted from Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199215626) (2007).

The starting point is the definition of the relation : "$(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ satisfies $\varphi$ in $\mathcal A$" [page 141] :

> If $\varphi$ is atomic then $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ satisfies $\varphi$ in $\mathcal A$ if and only if
>
> $\mathcal A \vDash \varphi [t_1/y_1, \ldots, t_n/y_n]$
>
> where $t_1, \ldots, t_n$ are closed terms (possibly witnesses) such that for each $i, (t_i)_A = a_i$.

In rough terms, for each $i$, $t_i$ is a "name" for the object $a_i \in \mathcal A$.

Then, starting from the "basic" definition [page 169] :

> Suppose $\varphi(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ is a formula, $\mathcal A$ a structure and $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ an $n$-tuple of elements of $\mathcal A$.
>
> Recall that we say that $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ satisfies $\varphi$ in $\mathcal A$, if the sentence $\varphi[\overline a_1/y_1, \ldots, \overline a_n/y_n]$ is true in $\mathcal A$, where each $\overline a_i$ is a constant symbol (if necessary a witness) naming $a_i$.

we have the clause regarding *satisfaction* for formulae with the universal quantifier [page 170] :

> If $\varphi$ is $\forall x \psi$, then $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ satisfies $\varphi$ in $\mathcal A$ if and only if for every element $a \in \mathcal A$, $(a_1, \ldots, a_n, a)$ satisfies $\psi(y_1, \ldots, y_n, x)$.

See the comments [page 163] regarding the case of "nested" quantifiers, and the **Remark** [page 166] :

> notice that the model checking went in the opposite direction from the way we assigned a truth value to a propositional formula in a structure

i.e. it "works" starting from the complete formula and "unpacking" it.

In our case, when we "remove" the outer quantifier, no free occurrences of $x$ will "surface"; thus, the evaluation process of the first $\forall$ has no effect, because there is no free occurrence of $x$ to be "filled".